# perl regex style, using m!$regex! versus

Tags: regex, perl

source string:

1. Mandarin Chinese (1.1 billion)
2. Hindi/Urdu (350 million)
3. Spanish (330 million)
4. English (300 million)
5. Arabic (200 million)

Trying to extract just the language name.

I have this code currently that works

```
 if($line =~ m!\s(.*)\(!)
    {
      print $1 . "\n" ;
    }
```

But I am trying to use the quotemeta function to do it which I cant seem to be able to do.

```
  my $regex = quotemeta( "\s(.*)\(" );
#Also tried as i suspect the \s is my problem.
  my $regex = quotemeta( "\\s(.*)\(" );


  if($line =~ m/$regex/)
    {
      print $1 . "\n" ;
    }
```

Is any style preferred over the other one?

Comment: I am new to perl and regex, let me edit my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't understand what you're trying to use [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) for.

If you've got actual regex language, then you *don't* want to quote it.

```
my $regex = qr/\s(.*)\(/;
if ($line =~ /$regex/) ...
```

If you do want to quote it (you want to exactly match the string `\s(..*)\(`), you don't need `quotemeta` explicitly, but this is effectively what you're doing now.

```
my $str = '\s(.*)\(';
if ($line =~ /\Q$str\E/) ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I was mistaken i need the quotemeta function to help me escape special character for regex to work in perl because other wise it confuses with the brackets in my regex, qr// worked for me thanks

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @ephemient that quotemeta isn't needed here.

I would use the `/x` modifier to make the regexp more readable :

```
  if($line =~ m/ \s (.*) \( /x )
```

and taking it  step further

```
if($line =~ m/ 
    \s      # space
    (.*)    # capture  anything 
    \(      # up to and not including a (
  /x )
```

A refinement. Currently you are capturing the space after `English`. I would add

```
if($line =~ m/ 
    \s      # space
    (.*)    # capture  anythin 
    \s+    # up to and not including space
    \(      #  a (
  /x )
```

Finally - look and see what your program does if you give it

```
1. English (GB) (300 million) 
2. Arabic (200 million (2005 value))
```

One works, the other doesnt. It might be worht understanding why!

Comment: That’s “slash x”, not “backslash x”.

Comment: its the greedy vs non-greedy stuff :)
change (.*) to (.*?), thanks for helping!